# Build answer with opposite attribute of first answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My form creates a question and answers. For true and false I currently have one answer being submitted that is the correct answer. I am trying to figure out how to make another answer with the same attributes except have the opposite value, either True or False.

Since the answers are created with the question I'm not sure what to do. I was thinking of the controller having something like, @question.answers.build(question: params[:content]) but am lost. Is there a @question.answers.build.where(content: (@question.content.opposite)) or something? Any help aprreciated

The controller:

```
def new_tf
@question = Question.new
@question.answers.build
end

def create
@question = Question.new(question_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @question.save
    format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @question }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
end

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:content, :question_type, :category, :product_id, :active, :user_id, answers_attributes: [ :content, :correct, :question_id ] ).
  merge user_id: current_user.id
end
```

The form:

```
<h1>New True/False Question</h1>
<%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
<%= form_for @question, url: new_tf_question_path(@question) do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/error_questions' %>

  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :content, class: "input-lg" %>

<%= f.label :category %><br>
<%= f.select :category, [ ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Surveillance", "ip_video_surveillance"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"] ], {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>

<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a product"}, {class: "form-control input-lg"} %>

<%= f.label :active %><br>
<%= f.check_box :active %>

<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>

<%= render 'tf_answers', :f => builder %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.select :question_type, [["True False", "TF"]], {class: "form-control input-lg"}, style: "visibility: hidden" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Question", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary", style: "margin-top: 45px;" %>

<% end %>
```

The _tf_answers.erb.rb

```
<%= f.check_box :correct, {checked: true, style: "visibility: hidden"} %>
<%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
<%= f.text_field :content, :value => 'True', :readonly => true, :class => "input-lg", :id => "answer" %>
<%= button_tag "Toggle True/False", :id => "toggle", :class => "btn btn-small btn-inverse", :type => "button" %>

<script>
function checkAnswer() {
var answer = $('#answer').val();
if ('False' == answer) {
    $("#answer").val('True');
} else {
    $("#answer").val('False');
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle').click(function () {
checkAnswer();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new answer after the first one saved.

```
if @question.save
    @answer = Answer.find_by_question_id(@question.id)
    if @answer.content == "True"
      Answer.create(content: "False", question_id: @answer.question_id, correct: false)
    end
    if @answer.content == "False"
      Answer.create(content: "True", question_id: @answer.question_id, correct: false)
    end
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't your model automatically create both answers?  Extend the save method in your model and you won't have to have this logic in your controller.  It probably belongs there anyway.

Comment: It is only making one answer in the new_tf method. If I wanted to make two I would use 2.times {@question.answers.build}. If I did that I would have to have one hidden answer. But since the build is building the same answer twice I can't do that. The answer is made twice from the same code.